# Reading a CSV file then re-exporting it as a CSV file to Excel

Tags: c#

I have already read the csv file, Now i simply want to re export it back to excel to view the changes made on the file. i have also tried to used Excel as an extensive automation API but do not know how to do this process.

```
public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            // Skip the line with column names
            if (i == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Splitting by space. I assume this is the pattern
            var replace = lines[i].Replace(' ', ',');

            results.Add(replace);
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: when i run the program console application i do see the changes. However i would like the view the same changes in Excel but i do not know how to do this process

Comment: Put that information in the question please. And also say what you have tried (Excel has an extensive automation API).

Comment: Are you just looking for `File.WriteAllLines(fileName, results);`? -- Btw. if you always skip the first line, you can change the `for` loop to `for (var i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)` (maybe with a check that `lines.Length > 0` first).

Comment: the code which i currently solved my solution i would like to export this updated file to excel or save the file as a text file

Comment: If you want to see the "live" changes in excel - as you said - then just add a reference to the Excel Object Libary and work with the Application class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for some *Linq*, an implementation like this

```
   var target = File
     .ReadLines(fileName)
     .Skip(1) // Skip the line with column names
     .Select(line => line.Replace(' ', ',')); // ... I assume this is the pattern

   // Writing back to some other file
   File.WriteAllLines(someOtherFileName, target);

   // In case you want to write to fileName back, materialize:
   // File.WriteAllLines(fileName, target.ToList());
```

Comment: thanks for the solution i implemented in my code it works perfectly how i decide to not to skip the column names but would like to include them. have you any idea on how to include them back.

Comment: @user5813072: if you don't want to *skip*, just comment out/remove `Skip(1)`